# are the mediapipe samples still using the old mediapipe or have they been upgraded?

Tags: mediapipe

With the new mediapipe solution is support for c/c++ dropped ?
Or is there still a way to get access to all the new combined models ?

Are the examples in mediapipe/examples/* using the old mediapipe or have they been updated ?